# Share screen in safari 13 with agora sdk

Tags: safari, agora.io, agora-web-sdk-ng

I am using agora-rtc-sdk 3.3.0. When i click on "share screen" and gave permission (problem is not with getDisplayMedia) safari reload page. The line which cause it, is client.publish(stream), if comment this line stream created successfully (according to console), same as client but i cant publish my "screen sharing" stream. This bug appears only in safari 13, other browsers works fine. Adding this part of code.

```
const beginShare = async() => {
    agoraShareStream = AgoraRTC.createStream({
      streamID: SHARE_ID,
      audio: false,
      video: false,
      screen: true
    });

await agoraShareStream.init(() => {
  console.log('init local stream success')
});

setShareStream(agoraShareStream);

enqueueSnackbar("Started screen sharing", { variant: "info" });
```

}

```
const createShareClient = async() => {
    const agoraShareClient = AgoraRTC.createClient({
      mode: "rtc",
      codec: "vp8"
    });

await agoraShareClient.init(appId);

await agoraShareClient.join(getAgoraToken({ uid: SHARE_ID, channel }), channel, SHARE_ID);

agoraShareClient.publish(agoraShareStream);

setShareClient(agoraShareClient);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Agora doesn't support screen sharing on Safari as noted in the documentation here: https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/screensharing_web?platform=Web#introduction

> The Agora RTC Web SDK supports screen sharing in the following desktop browsers:
>
> - Chrome 58 or later
> - Firefox 56 or later
> - Edge 80 or later on Windows 10+